# How can I change from one project of Laravel to another in the localhost:8000?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, serve

I started a new project on Laravel, and i want to visualize the Home on `localhost:8000`. But when I try it, I keep getting the home from another project that I was working on before.

How can I access my new project?

I tried the command `php artisan serve` on the folder of the new project, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cafe
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: If you are running on a linux or a macOS system, you can check what's serving on port 8000 by executing this command:
`lsof -i:8000 -P -n`. Then you can terminate it.

Answer (score 1):

It kinda depends on what type of system and setup you are working on.
You can use

```
php artisan serve --port='yourdesiredport'
```

or if you are using vagrant and homestead you can create custom virtual hosts for each project like sub domains:

```
project1.com, project2.com etc.
```

or if you are on windows and using WAMPP OR XAMPP you can create virtual hosts or change 
default route for root directory in httpf.conf

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Please use different port

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```